# Can I dynamicaly size a div based on discrete units and still center?

Tags: css

Here's the problem:  I have a website I'm working on that, depending on what the user has selected, will pop up a different number of boxes 80px high and 200px wide and currently set to float:left.  These boxes are contained within a div that is basically the whole width of the screen minus some 1% margins.

So at the moment they all fill in the box and, depending on screen size, occupy a grid of variable height and width.  The problem is, if the screen size makes the containing box, say, 700px wide then you end up with 3 boxes per row and a bloody big margin on the right.

What I would like to do is center the grid of boxes inside the containing box so that the margins are equal left and right.  I suspect this can't be done since it means the containing box needs to set its size by looking both at the size of the user's window as well as the size of its children.  It would be easy to do with javascript but I'd prefer not to if that is an option.  If it is truly impossible then I will simply script it and let non-js users see a left-justified set of boxes.

Edit:
Okay.  The relevant markup bit:

```
<div class="itemcontainer">
<?php
  ... some php code to generate a query and run it
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
        echo '<div class="itembox">'.$row['comname'].'<br<i>'.
              $row['sciname'].'</i></div>';
   }
?>      
</div>
```

And the css with borders/colours etc. removed for clarity:

.itemcontainer {position:relative; width:98%;  left:1%;}
.itembox {float:left; margin:5px; height:80px; width:200px;}

As you can see, it is currently set so that the containing box is basically fixed to the window width with a 1% margin.  What I'd like to do is have it hug a discrete number of itemboxes .. which will vary depending on how wide the screen is.  I suppose I can provide an online version but currently it is on my computer whose native server is intentionally isolated from the big bad internet. :-D

Comment: Could you show some mark-up and CSS? Possibly even the current state online somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` and `auto` center that child:

`.itembox { margin:5px auto; height:80px; width:200px;}`

Removing the float will prevent additional children from moving up in the document - making a "3-in-a-row" impossible (div elements force a line break unless 'float' or 'position' are used to take them out of the layout hierarchy).

If you want "3-in-a-row", you can change `.itembox` to be an inline-block element and apply centering to its parent:

```
.itemcontainer { text-align:center; ... }
.itembox { display:inline-block; margin:5px; .... } /* a 700px wide viewport should allow for 3 per row */
```

There are some caveats to this that you should consider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Either way, using 'float' on '.itembox' is prob causing most of your frustration at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.itemcontainer {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The display:table shrinks the size of the container according to the content (like a table does) and the margin: auto makes an equal right and left margin.